# How to Install Office 365 version 2002 on Windows 7

Tags: microsoft-office-365

We have a few legacy Windows 7 machines in our environment (long story) that have old versions of MS Office.  While MS 365 is no longer supported on Windows 7, MS 365 Apps at version 2002 will at least continue receiving security updates until 2023.

Per Microsoft: "[This means that if you want to continue to deploy and update Microsoft 365 Apps on devices that are running Windows 7, you need to use Version 2002](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/endofsupport/windows-7-support)"

So perhaps a dumb question: **how can we get an installer specific to MS 365 Apps version 2002**?

Comment: I believe that's where the Office Deployment Tool (ODT) comes into play.  See: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2280681-office-deployment-tool-previous-version-office-365-to-run-on-windows-7

Answer (score 4):

As Grey Askew suggested, you need the ODT to install Microsoft 365 apps with sepcificed version.

**Step 1**: Download and extract ODT.

[Office Deployment Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49117)

**Step 2**: Write the configuration file (.xml ) as following. I also suggest you put it together with ODT.

```
<Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64"
      Channel="SemiAnnual"
      Version="16.0.12527.20880" >
    <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
</Configuration>
```

- Via this configuration file, the Version 2002 (Build 12527.20880) I specificed is the first Version 2002 for Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel.
- To check the version number of Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel, please
  refer to "[Update history for Microsoft 365 Apps (listed by
  date)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date)".
- For other ODT options, you may refer to
  "[Configuration options for the Office Deployment Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office-deployment-tool-configuration-options)".

**Step 3**: Run Command Prompt as administrator, enter commands to install Office.

- Use "cd" command to locate to the forlder includes ODT and the
  configuration file.
- And then enter "**setup.exe /configure** *configuration file name*"
- For more, here is an article "[Overview of the Office Deployment
  Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-office-deployment-tool)" you may have look.

Please also note, [TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are disabled for Microsoft 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/tls-1.0-and-1.1-deprecation-for-office-365?view=o365-worldwide), you need to ensure TLS 1.2 is avaliable, otherwise Microsoft 365 apps could not be activated.